# How is the learning process for a NN implemented?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

Thanks to [BP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) and some scoring/loss functions, a NN can train to do the job as demanded. Or at least try to do so.
I think I've understood BP but still I wonder about the following:

Let's say there is a certain NN and the input is a single number. The NN will propagate the information through all layers and all weights and activation functions and so on will finally output a single number as well. If the output number is the same as the input number, nothing will happen. In case, it is different, the error will result in a change of the weights such that the NN will provide this number according to that certain input number.
I think I also understood this.

What I don't get is: How is it done such that the NN can handle multiple/different inputs?

Assume $x = 3$.
The NN will now adjust the weights to provide this as output.
Next iteration, $x = 8$.
The NN will now adjust the weights to provide this as output.

From my understanding, the NN is now trained to put out $8$. And it lost its capability to reconstruct $3$.
Obviously this is not the fact. So how is it done that the NN can handle both the $x = 3$ and $x = 8$?

Something like a lookup table is probably too plain (and dumb). I think the NN learns to generate something like a (single) function. Does that make sense?

[image: nn]

Despite that, what does the implementation concept look like? Just the idea of it.

Comment: On the other hand, you seem uncertain of whether a neural network is a mathematical expression (it is) or a lookup table (it is not). But your citation of the backpropagation article seems to indicate that you know that a neural network is a mathematical expression because the whole article is oriented around explaining how to update weights and biases to predict inputs well. So I don't understand what it is you're asking: do you need confirmation that a neural network is not a lookup table? Or an explanation of how a neural network makes a prediction?

Comment: The latter :) Yes, finally it is about the prediction. This is actually the precise question I am concerned with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node is a (usually non-linear) function that combines the input. The entirety of the neural network is an additive model of nodes that in turn are connected to either the next hidden layer, or the output layer. Training learns the weight of connections: How different combinations of the input relate to the output.

> From my understanding, the NN is now trained to put out 8.

This is where your confusion arises. The networks has learned neither to output $8$, nor $3$, but instead how to combine the input such that the *predicted* output is close to the *actual* recorded output.$^\dagger$

I may be reading too much into your question, but it also seems you might be confused about what the input is: It is possible for the input to be the same as the output (this is the case for [autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder)), but more generally, you have a completely different input (e.g. images of animals) used to learn the output (e.g. the type of animal).

$\dagger$: I say *close* because we do not want to learn how the input relates output of the *sample*, but rather how the input of any sample from this population relates to the outcome of any sample from this population. If it would predict exactly the recorded output in the sample (e.g. $8$ and $3$), the problem is either very simple, or it is [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you're right, I am diving into Autencoders so I didn't pay attention how I describe my question. Nevertheless, let's say the NN learns a specific output for a specific input. How does it..  generalize? Why or how do different inputs result in different outputs? What actually is the crucial component for that? Is it "just" a n-dimensional function?

Comment: @Ben Okay, think of it this way: From a suitable random initialization, each example shifts the weights *slightly* towards a state that would minimize the reconstruction error on that example. By seeing many different examples, each of which shifts the state of the neural network *slightly* towards one that would recover that particular example, the network will learn combinations of features that occur in many different examples, not something about any specific example. That way, if those relevant combinations also exist in unseen data, it can generalize to some larger population.

Comment: @Ben In addition, mini batch sizes are usually greater than $1$, in which case backpropagation moves along the gradient of a multitude of examples.

Comment: I think I understand it conceptually but still can't figure out how it works on a low-level(?). For example, the input for a NN is typically/always(?) an array of numbers. When I use the gradient, it will result in a zero.
When you describe that different examples "shift the state of the NN towards one which would recover the examples" -> What exactly is this state? How is it embodied? And/or even implemented?

Comment: The state refers to the current set of weights and biases.

Comment: Well, but how can one set of weights and biases (representing such a state) satisfy lots of several inputs? I understand how it works for a single number, but how does it work for..  100000 numbers?

Comment: A neural network needs input. If given nothing, it does not say "8" or "3"or anything else. It works just like any function. A simple linear regression can also predict an output for 100000 different numbers. Suppose you have some very simply function $f(x)=\beta x$. If you input $6$ and the recorded output is $3$, then the weight ($\beta$) moves towards $0.5$. If you then have another example with input $16$ and the recorded outcome is $8$, the single weight moves further towards $0.5$. Do this enough times and you learn the function $f(x)=0.5 \cdot x$. (...)

Comment: (...) Now consider an example with noise: The input is still $6$, but the output is $3.014\dots$. By using a low enough learning rate, we move *towards* $\hat{\beta}=0.507\dots$, but not *exactly* there. Repeat for another noisy example: Input $16$, recorded output $7.924\dots$, we this time move *towards* $\hat{\beta}=0.495\dots$. Repeat this many times and we (hopefully) learn the function that generalizes towards a larger group $f(x)=0.5\cdot x$. The big difference in a neural network is the number of parameters, but it still works like any other function.

Comment: Finally: A new, unseen observation. This time we only have an input, $x=4$. Can you see now how we can arrive at $y=2$? We can enter any number for $x$ and it will still produce an output. Same goes for the function a neural network learns.

Comment: To conclude: A NN is basically a function and learning literally means, constructing this function? When I try to see that visually, it looks like quite the opposite of a SVM. There, a function is drawn inside the space to separate the data and none is incident with the function while a NN constructs a function where as most as data points live in as possible :)

Comment: Yeah, with the caveat that we don't just want a network so vastly overcomplete that it can memorize the training data. Instead, it should learn the *structural* part of the data-generating process, while ignoring the noise. In other words, we don't want it to learn which specific input corresponds to which specific output, we want it to learn how input in general relates to output.